# videos are not playing on google help site(material design guide), google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

For example, this page [example](http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/authentic-motion.html) In dev tools console errors are shown, for each video, like this

> OPTIONS http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/videos/animation-authentic-motion-authenticMotion_massAndWeight_ex1_large_xhdpi.webm Origin hxxp://www.google.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. authentic-motion.html:1

If link on video in console clicked, video played at new page. In firefox all is ok - all the videos playing as embedded as intended.

Adblock and flashblock plugins were disabled but this did not help.
I have read about this error - this is security protection feature, but why this is error on google site? And how to tweak/whitelist site?

Answer (score 1):

seems like my firefox had the same problem with the material page videos from google.
Inspect Element showed the page trying to connect to "encrypted.google.com", so the easy solution was putting a "https://" in front of the url in the address bar of the browser
Like magic everything works.
Dont ask me why firefox jumps on the page with http:// instead https://
hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when I open the page in Chrome, and I have AdBlock pro enabled. Have you ensured that JavaScript is enabled, plugins are allowed to run, and cookies (and possibly images) are enabled in chrome://settings ?

Comment: First I tried at Ubuntu 13.10 x86, but now I tried it in windows and it works even with adblock and other plugins(same as in ubuntu - account sync) enabled - so problem I guess in build for ubuntu.

Comment: yup, sounds like it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the google domain country code in addition to adding "https://"

e.g.
**I started with this:** 
www.google.com/ua/design/spec/animation/authentic-motion.html#authentic-motion-mass-weight

**but this got the videos to load:** https://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/authentic-motion.html#authentic-motion-mass-weight

Answer (score -1):

changing the domain also worked for me. google.co.in/... to google.com/...